# resultSet.getObject() возвращает пустую строку

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Программа должна отобразить данные зарегистрированных пользователей. При подключении к базе данных проблем не возникает, но resultSet.getString("ИМЯ СТОЛБЦА") возвращает пустой текст. А вот resultSet.getInt("UserID") возвращает все id (это по крайней мере значит, что связь с БД удалась). И вот что самое интересное: попробовал отобразить и числовые данные с помощью getInt (н.п. баланс), но они тоже не отображаются. Ничего не отображается кроме ID. Даже попробовал getObject() и metadata. В консоле отобразились только имена столбцов и ID.

Вот код, БД и консоль:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Conn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection2 = null;
        Statement statement2 = null;
        ResultSet resultSet2 = null;

        try {
            connection2 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ИМЯ", "ЛОГИН", "ПАРОЛЬ");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }

        try {
            statement2 = connection2.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            resultSet2 = statement2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM userdetails");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet2.getMetaData();
            int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                System.out.printf("%-8s\t", rsmd.getColumnName(i) + "   ");
            System.out.println();
            for (; resultSet2.next();) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++)
                    System.out
                            .printf("%-8s\t", resultSet2.getObject(j) + "   ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connection2.close();
                statement2.close();
                resultSet2.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В другом проекте в Eclipse те же методы отлично отображают таблицу еще одной базы на фрейме. Может быть проблема с БД? Перепробовал переключаться между разными версиями Java в Eclipse, загрузил последний коннектор, но ничего не выходит. Переписал БД krknutyun в фреймовый проект, на фрейм не отобразилось, а "рабочая" БД отобразилась в моей неработающей программе. Какие проблемы могут быть с БД krknutyun?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема решилась только после удаления базы и создания новой базы с нуля. В чем была проблема, никак не выяснилось. Наверно какая-то несовместимость шрифтов.

Comment: Тогда уж не шрифтов, а кодировки.

Comment: для начала выводите все ошибки внутри `catch`, java вам подскажет в чем дело.

Comment: никогда не оставляйте catch-блок пустым. Как минимум, добавьте вывод ошибки. И используйте try-with-resources из Java 7 (или 8)

Comment: на первый взгляд, у вас просто нет соответствующих полей в таблице. Exception не выводится, из-за работы с БД.

Answer (score 0):

1. вам там в catch блоке напишут в чём дело если стктрейс включить. раз id выводится, значит единствнная проблема это то, что не находится значение по ключю в reultSet-е. если такого поля нет, то и кинется ошибка.
2. в запросе при обращении по resultSet.getString("ИМЯ СТОЛБЦА") НИКОГДА не используйте имя столбца. всегда прописывайте as и ищите по нему. не найдёте - вывалится ошибка. 
   очень абстрактный пример..

   ```
   String sql = "select group as GrpID from groups";
   ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   while (res.next()) {
       switch (res.getString("GrpID")) {
           case "23": GrpID = "83"; break;
           case "0":  GrpID = "81"; break;
           case "20": GrpID = "85"; break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: **НИКОГДА не используйте имя столбца** - это откуда такая инфа?

Comment: Например вам захотелось в запросе  формировать название таблицы из которой будете вынимать данные(удобный вариант месячной смены логов типа incoming_session_202001), а там поля в стиле таблица.поле.  
 Комбинация "таблица.поле" будет переменной. а по as константой.

Comment: плюс orm модель(jpa, hibernate) например в java управляет названием полей таблицы и они могут поменяться при редактировании (@Entity @Table(name = "gps_points"),   @Column(name = "latitude") и т.д.) что не заметит правильно написанный код, а вот прямые запросы в базу почуют сразу и чтоб переписывать только запрос, в котором выкинется ошибка, а не всё, что там последует в логике выемки из ResultSetов лучше юзать через as.
 Разумеется это только совет. а не инструкция.

Comment: _Например вам захотелось_ - есть кейсы, где это будет возможно удобно, но говорить прям `НИКОГДА не используейте` - такое себе. По поводу orm - если у вас есть orm, вам вряд ли нужно писать ручной запрос, а если уж и пришлось - то на это должны быть тесты. и если тесты упадут, потому что не нашлось колонки - уж поправить запрос всегда можно. не увидел реально полезного аргумента за "НИКОГДА не используйте имя столбца"